How to Add Custom Checkstyle Version in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2024.1.1?
I recently upgraded to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2024.1.1 and encountered an issue with the Checkstyle plugin. My project uses a specific version of Checkstyle defined in checkstyle.xml which isn't compatible with the versions pre-filled in the Checkstyle configuration window of IntelliJ.
Previously, there was an option to add a custom Checkstyle version by pointing to a downloaded .jar file, but this option seems to be missing in the latest version of the plugin or IDE.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
Looking for an option to add a custom Checkstyle version in the plugin settings (no such option exists now).
Checking IntelliJ’s documentation and forums for any updates regarding Checkstyle integration (found no relevant information).
I am looking for a way to integrate my specific Checkstyle version directly into IntelliJ to continue using the IDE’s Checkstyle functionalities. Does anyone know of a method to manually add a Checkstyle version in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2024.1.1, or is there an alternative approach to handle this situation effectively?

You could run Checkstyle as a command line app using IntelliJ. But then you'd only get the results in a terminal view rather than the code editor.
On the other hand, there is a mapping of compatible versions in the plugin. This should mean that you can just enter your version of Checkstyle in .idea\checkstyle-idea.xml (while IntelliJ is shut down), and the plugin will replace it with a compatible version that should work with your config file just fine.
<entry value="10.18.2" key="checkstyle-version"/>

